# Any good examples for using sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to figure out the native packager plugin for use in by sbt.

Are there any good sources / examples for me to go through apart from the one in https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

Any examples where it is used in Build.scala instead of build.sbt types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a set of examples in the src/sbt-test of sbt-native-packager.   However, there are a bunch of other open source projects which use it:

- <strike>https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/full-packaging/project/packaging.scala#L6</strike>
- https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/project/Packaging.scala#L18
- <strike>https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/blob/master/project/scalainstaller.scala#L12</strike>

(posted from google groups of sbt)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example I have found.

https://github.com/pussinboots/sbt-rpm

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Below is a list of examples using sbt-native-packager:

https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples